# How to map exception for gwt-resty

Tags: gwt, jersey

I am currently using gwt-resty and jersey for the server side. The problem I have run into is how do I map an exception for the MethodCallback implementation. I have created an ExceptionMapper which converts the exception to json and returns it in json format but the onFailure method is giving me the generic error message for my exception, "Failed BAD Request"

The question is how do I convert the exception into something that gwt-resty can process the exception in order to get the message from the server side exception.

Here is my service implementation

```
    service.getCurrentAddress("123456", new MethodCallback<Address>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Method method, Address response) {
            Window.alert("Got your address" + response);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Method method, Throwable e) {
            GWT.log("failed", e);
            GWT.log("Failed " + e.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Here is my exception mapper.

```
@Provider
public class VendorExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Exception> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Exception exception) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).entity(exception).build();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understood your question but I think that you can parse Throwable e to get your exception in case of failure.

You can also intercept your exception by coding a restyGWT dispatcher and treat it before entering the onFailure().

Comment: Hi. I'm also trying to parse my specific exception from the Throwable, but I'm not sure how. any examples ? I already asked this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24367278/restgwt-repsonse-exceptions. thx

Comment: Use instanceof to try convert it into a WebApplicationException or whatever exection you have created